# JasperException occurs when integrating Struts2,Hibernate with Enterprise application

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2, web-frameworks

I have a web applications built with Struts2, Hibernate and It works fine.

I create a new **Enterprise application** in NetBean. The web application I built was added into the **Enterprise application** as a Java EE module. I have choose the Client Module as the web application and tried to run the **Enterprise application**.

However, the web applications didn't work. It told me

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The Struts dispatcher cannot be found.  

This is usually caused by using Struts tags without the associated filter. 

Struts tags are only usable when the request has passed through its servlet filter, 

which initializes the Struts dispatcher needed for this tag. - [unknown location]
```

Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Once I remove the web application from the **Enterprise application** and to clean and build. The web application is just workable.

**Supplementary:**

I have added the libraries in the Enterprise application just like the following picture, and have changed the `filter`.But the error still occurs.
[image]
[image]

Comment: which version fo struts2 are you using

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have configured the buildpath/classpath when you added the web application as Enterprise application as JavaEE module correctly. There might be some dependencies unresolved hence it could not find the Struts dispatcher.

**Note:** The FilterDispatcher filter is deprecated since Struts version 2.1.3. If you are using latest version of Struts2 ( > 2.1.3) use

org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter

instead.
And since you are getting JasperException. YOu need to know few things Why this exception occurs:

- It is occurs whenever you miss the tags, or did not close tags properly
- When you are JSP is not parsed by the  jasper engine then it throw  jasper Exception.
  Means If you are writing the jsp code not properly and if you put any unavailable resources in the jsp then we will get Jasper Exception
- The following reasons may have to get the jasper Exception.

  1.jsp-api.jar is missing in the build path.

  1. Jsp code is not written properly.

Comment: I will try to configure the build path in the Enterprise application :) By the way I am using 2.3.4, I will try change it to `org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter` :)

Answer (score 0):

Just like @DarkHorse mentioned, you should not use `FilterDispatcher`, please change it to `org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter`.

It seems you don't have all the dependencies included. make sure you have following dependencies in your classpath:
[image]